# database and java

Tags: java, mysql

i am a student. i have to do the individual project about a system. the system must be done using the console not the web base. so i`m using netbeans version 6.9 and mysql version 5.2. my problem is i do not know how to connect them.
hopefully, you all can help me...
thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

Use [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/products/jdbc/overview.html) if you want to learn how things work. Most of the [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tools are built on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue seems to be the vocabulary you have used.
What you are trying to do is: "Connect to the SQL database through Netbeans."

Here's a tutorial:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html

Voice of experience:
Always check the developer's homepage for tutorials and manuals.  It's surprising to find that most seemingly original questions have been comprehensively answered, or partially (yet sufficiently) answered.  Conversely, there's no surprise in finding that the technical support community exacerbates peoples problems with their generally hideous intolerance of people who do not take this step for some reason or another.  It's likely that someone who seems to have not read the manual, cover-to-cover, will be verbally abused.  The assumption is: "all technically minded people should love reading manuals".  The truth is: "reading manuals isn't fun until about year 7".  Of course, there are rare exceptions to the cultural/social problem we've got. ;)  I think some people enjoy the manuals straight away, too.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html) describes how to use Java JDBC to connect to MySQL and perform SQL queries, database inserts and deletes.